# Audio recording to SoundCloud

Tags: javascript, audio, soundcloud, audio-recording

I need to add an ability to record audio to our site and upload it to our soundCloud account.
The recordings are fairly short - 2 min max.

1: What is the easiest way to do it? Any good tutorials out there? 
I was hoping to find a widget to embed. Something like this:

[image]

Do I have to send the file to my server (Java)? 
The soundcloud api [doc](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#recording) contains a [sample](http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/recording.html) but the button skin looks bad and you have to go through the connect flow.

Thanks